# Play raw h264 annexB with html <video> element

Tags: video-streaming, mp4, h.264, nvidia, mpeg-4

I use the library Nvidia Encoder SDK (C++) to generate a raw H264 stream (Annex B). I don't record the stream into a file, I just want to broadcast the video in live to a HTML video element.

So, I would like to know what I need to do ? Do I need to mux the raw H264 stream into a MP4 container ? Using Annex B is not a problem for live streaming ? Can I use HTTP protocol ?

Thanks for your answer.